# restore complete filesystem to default security context

Tags: centos, selinux

I'm a selinux newbie and had to change the security context of a mercurial repo and config file on a CentOS box to get it serves from httpd.

Accidentally I issued "chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_script_exec_t /", which I could only stop when already masses of files and directories have been modified.

I read about restorecon to restore something to its default context, but it doesn't work for me, I got "permission denied".

What can I do to restore the whole filesystem to its selinux defaults?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a [fixfiles relabel](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-fsrelabel.html) to get things back in order. Else you could edit */etc/selinux/config* and set the system to no longer enforce SELinux. Good luck!

Comment: There likely is a reason why SELinux is used in enforcing mode. It therefore is bad advise to switch to another mode or disable SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

You could either of the following to fix this.

1. fixfiles
2. create a file `/.autorelabel` and reboot the system.
3. restorecon -f file 
   Usually the conf file will be `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts`